# In angular, while adding child component, do we need to map all child Output variables?

Tags: angular, parent-child

Example:
Parent -----

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `<div> Test
                   <child [modal] = "parentModal"
                          (change) = "onChange($event)">
                   </child>
                </div>`
})

export class ParentComponent {
    parentModal;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.parentModal = "I am Parent";
    }

    onChange(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }

}
```

Child -----

```
@Component({
     selector: 'child',
     template: `<div>
                    {{modal}}
                    <a (click)="emitClick()"></a>
                </div>`
})

export class ChildComponent {
    @Input modal;
    @Output change;
    @Output open;


    emitClick() {
        this.change.emit();
    }
}
```

My code might have wrong syntax. Please correct it if you find some.

My Question:

As you can see Parent is not passing `Open` Parameter to child. Will it result in error when emitClick function is called on click to `A` tag?

Comment: No mapping of all output and input variables are not compulsory. It's just that if you need to pass it for some activity, and they are not there you code might break, due to undefined, unless you have taken care of the scenario. If output is not mapped to parent and you have a event subscribe function that depends on a open output event, say for example, then the event listener will not be triggered since event is not captured in template. That's all. But again, it's not a compulsion. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Long Story Short, No, you don't. But your code should be:

> parent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `<div> Test
                   <child [modal] = "parentModal"
                          (change) = "onChange($event)">
                   </child>
                </div>`
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    public parentModal = "I am Parent";

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    onChange(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }

}
```

> child

```
@Component({
     selector: 'child',
     template: `<div>
                    {{modal}}
                    <a (click)="emitClick()"></a>
                </div>`
})

export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() modal: string = '';
    @Output() change = new EventEmitter<string>();
    @Output() open= new EventEmitter<void>();


    emitClick() {
        this.change.emit('change');
    }
}
```